# iOS-Charts Library: BarChart background color fill

Tags: ios, charts, background, uicolor, ios-charts

I am using a Charts library by Daniel Gindi.
I need to make a diagram like in this screenshot. Set a different background color. Could you do that? I looked at the library and found no way to do this.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Daniel Gindi's Charts library? https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts
Or do you use this library? 
https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes i use the library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 0):

There is [a nice tutorial on AppCoda for iOS charts by Daniel Gindi](http://appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial).

"If you want a different color for each data entry, then you have to provide as many colors as the total number of data entries you have".

In order to change the color of the bar chart, you'll need to change the color of the dataset you're representing. Like so:

`chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 126/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)]`

If you mean to change the chart's background color, you need to put this in your code:
`chart.backgroundColor = .white`

Comment: There are blue, green, red bars. How to change the colors of the bars I understand. However, I don’t understand how to fill the background with the color of the bars. To get the background is divided into sections.

Comment: I've reproduced the BarChart and was trying to find the way. Well, my decision is that it's impossible to do. However, you could make a custom BarChart and implement your own solution for doing what you need. Look, if you will have three different data sets, the values will most likely be the same (like in your screen), so the bars may be represented like so - a green bar, a red one, a blue one - and all with the same values. I will add the screenshot of what I mean - I added the same values for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

Look, I specifically added the same arrays of data, and I added them to one bar chart. What I mean is that the same values alternate. They aren't represented one after another. So, it means that if you had a different background color for each bar, this wouldn't probably look nice imho.
I hope someone else will try to reproduce your question so that we have more opinions here :)

[image: Bar Data]

Answer (score 0):

Use following configuration to barchar

```
 barChart.drawBarShadowEnabled = true
```

Then use

```
chartDataSet.barShadowColor = .systemGray5
```

It works.